# How can I remove Ubuntu 13.04 while keeping the existing Windows 7 intact?

Tags: uninstall

I installed 13.04 but it not installed correctly. I want to remove it and keep my Windows OS intact in the process.

Comment: I've found that the best way to get anyone to help with any issues (especially computer issues) is to provide a reasonable amount of detail. For instance, how did you Install Ubuntu? Did you use WOBI? Or, did you install from a bootable medium (CD, Flashdrive...). Describing your partition setup might also help.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to do this is to burn ubunut 13.04 to an USB stick, boot from it, reinstall Ubuntu. You can overwrite the old one in the process: it should be one of the options given to you while installing. Somewhere in the installation grub will be installed and grub will autodetect Windows 7. So, in short: reinstall ubunut on the same partition as it is now, and Windows 7 will be untouched.